# How to count total length of a string after html_entity_decode()

Tags: php, sql

I am using TinyMCE which is just a what you see is what you get text area to input my post data into my database 
the problem I am facing is I have to display 20 characters of data in my first page but I don't know how

I have tried to make a function to show whole data if it`s character is less than 20 and only show 20 character if they are more

```
function displayString($str){
        if(strlen($str) < 20){
            return $str;    
        }else{
            return(substr($str, 0,20)."...");
        }

    }
displayString(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($content)));
```

The problem I am facing is, it`s counting element before html_entity_decode but I want to receive the number of string after it convert, so is there any algorithm to perform this?

Comment: Do not use utf8_decode.

Comment: @Dharman still the same problem

Comment: Please provide an example input string, and explain what exactly the problem is with that.

Comment: @misorude When I save data it saved as &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;asasddsa&lt;/strong&gt;&lt   like this but I want to count the number of text part only that is asasddsa

Comment: and return only 20 characters only if its greater than 20 char

Comment: html_entity_decode does not _remove_ `&lt;`/`&gt;` etc., but translates them back into the actual characters. If you want only the text content of a string containing HTML, you could use strip_tags.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are showing does not strip the tags.
To do so, you should use:

```
function displayString($str){
    if(strlen($str) < 20){
       return $str;    
    }else{
        return(substr($str, 0,20)."...");
    }
}

var_dump(displayString(utf8_decode(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($content)))));
```